Does an eternal, or a long, past explain the Horizon problem?
I recently learned about the Horizon Problem (which is basically, how can the CMB be so homogenous when there are causally disconnected regions?).
As far as I understand, one approach to explain this is Inflation, which simply smoothes out differences, without requiring the regions to be causally connected.
I wonder if an eternal (or at least long, for some value of long) past, possibly before expansion starts, could also explain this. As in that case, there is enough time to reach thermal equilibrium. That of course immediately runs into the problem of why expansion starts at some point, but ignoring that, are there other issues that such a model would create?

The problem is that your universe becomes highly contrived.
A thermal system in equilibrium does not have the same temperature everywhere because temperature is  statistical property and there are always random fluctuations. If the expansion is slow enough then those fluctuations always average out to a constant temperature, but the expansion of the early universe was too fast for this to happen.
The expansion not only expands the fluctuations but also amplifies them, so even starting from an initial equilibrium state we would now see those fluctuations as large non-uniformities. Inflation solves this by expanding the fluctuations to such an extreme extent that everything we can see today is a tiny part of a tiny fluctuation, though even with inflation we still see irregularities in the cosmic microwave background caused by random thermal fluctuations during the inflationary process.
It's possible a non-inflationary expansion could produce the universe we see today, but the expansion rate would have to be carefully controlled during the first few seconds and there is no known mechanism for this. Indeed short of some creator god taking a hand in the process it's hard to see how anything like that could have happened.
